# In Eclipse launch configurations for GWT and GAE, what's the difference between "GWT Application" and "Web Application?"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

There are two sorts of launch configurations, "GWT Application" and "Web Application" - what's the difference?

The [documentation for the plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0.html) doesn't ever mention "GWT Application," only "Web Application."

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html) (GWT) is a set of tools that lets you simplify web client-server interaction like Javascript/DOM/AJAX using Java.  It is not the same thing as Google App Engine.

FWIW, [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) now includes built-in support for GAE projects.  I prefer it to Google's Eclipse plugin.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the Eclipse launch configurations, not the products themselves.  You're right though, in that the question probably only makes sense if you're used to working on apps that involve both technologies.